# C++ using TR1 for basic dictionary lookup

Tags: c++, dictionary

This is my first time trying to use tr1. I'd like to make a dictionary of about 50000 words with only a lookup for word strings that simply returns something like a bool if it was found. I'm trying to understand this piece of code that I found.

Can somebody tell me if what I have here is a good start towards my goal?

What kind of performance can I expect on a 50000 word dictionary as is?

Also, can somebody explain this line of code to me?

```
found = it != words.end();
```

I've never seen this syntax before.

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string> Dictionary;
Dictionary words;    

std::ifstream word_is("eng_dict.txt");

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(word_is),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    std::inserter(words, words.begin()));

Dictionary::const_iterator it = words.find("hello");
        found = it != words.end();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would it help if I rewrote it as `found = (it != words.end());`?

Comment: Wait. Using TR1 in C++11/14 era?

Comment: @NickyC some implementations have not moved into that era yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TR1 is old stuff - it's from around 2005 - and most (if not all  of it) is now part of C++11 and there's no need to use the obsolete `tr1` bits anymore. Whatever resource you're using that contains this code, do yourself a favor and chuck it. Get a more modern book instead.

On the question of performance, It's unclear what answer you actually want, or what the question *really* is. I'll give you the standard answer: "*try it and find out.*"

As for the question re: syntax:

```
found = it != words.end();
```

Would it help if I rewrote it like this instead?

```
found = (it != words.end());
```

For future reference, you may want to consult the [C++ Operator Precedence Table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: 1-So I'll aim for "std::unordered_map" then... 2-ok...3-not really...mind explaining it in words? i see that there's a test to see if the iterator reached the end of the container and then assigned the result into 'found'. will it only work for iterators? will it only work for bool results? thanks

Comment: @Soran: You can use `std::unordered_set` if you want - it's in the standard now. As for the test, it will work in any comparison that's legal: `bool equal = (7 == 4)` means "if 7 is equal to 4 then `equal` will have the value `true` otherwise, it will have the value `false`". Basically is you can compare two things using `==` then you can use this syntax to get the result of the comparison.